# unique field validation fomular c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have a form with indexed  field(NAME) if i entre the same name an exception occured , i want a chek message validation telling me that the field name is unique i tried this code but it didn't work:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(ConstanteVM em)
    {
        try
        {

             if (!ModelState.IsValid||!ModelState.IsValidField(em.NOM)  )
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("NOM", " la constante est unique");

            }

             else if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               ConstanteVM assur = ServiceApplicatif.Save(em);

            }

     ViewData["ConstanteType"] = new SelectList(RefDataManager.GetRefData<ConstanteTypeVM>(), "ConstanteTypeCode", "ConstanteTypeLibelle");

            DataCache dataCache = new DataCache(CurrentSecurityContext.TenantID);
            dataCache.DropDataCache<ConstanteVM>();

            return View("Liste");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggerConstante.Error(string.Format("Exception : {0}", ex.Message.ToString()));
            throw new Exception("Erreur lors de l'enregistrement.");
        }
    }
```

Do i have to write a javascript code ?

Comment: Which line does the error occur? Also, I'm a little confused. So you want to add validation to the `Save` action that way, it tells you whether the name field `em.NOM` was already entered?

Comment: yes i want that . the first if (!ModelState.IsValid||!ModelState.IsValidField(em.NOM)  )
 if i enter a value of em.NOM existing already in the database :Exception("Erreur lors de l'enregistrement.");is occured (i have mentionned that the field have an index:'CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_NOM] ON [dbo].[T_CONSTANTE]
(
 [NOM] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO'

Comment: Okay, then you could either query the database directly (with LinQ), or catch the exception when it occurs and show it in the View. i.e., surround your action with a `try-catch` and handle the correct exception. It is generally better to have a validaitor function when putting things in the database though instead of relying on a `try-catch`

Comment: @ Infinitesimus i didn't understand you , what i must do in my dtabase?? whati need exactly is an alert when i enter an existing name  in my formular from my controller action mentionned earlier

Comment: Well, where do you store the first name (if you do)? It might not be in a database, maybe in memory, but basically when you get a name, you need to have a method that checks the new name against some place where you've stored all previous names. I think I don't understand your request well :/

Comment: @ Infinitesimus i stored the NAME and other field of the CONSTANTE table in a list .I have other table called RUBRIQUE which contains FORMULE as a field which contains NOM for exemple i have SARRA as a name and i have (SARRA *A-M)as FORMULE i want to interdict the delet of sarra becuse it is used in the RUBRIQUE TABLE there is my delet methode but it did'nt work